# How to determine Zodiac Sign in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, date

I have the following code:

```
NSDate *myDate = [datePickerControl date];
NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[format setDateFormat:@"dd-MM"];

NSString *getDate = [format stringFromDate:myDate];

NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"15-06",@"15-07",@"15-08",nil];

for (int i = 0; i < ([array count]); i++) {
    NSLog(@"i = %i", i);
    NSString *stringToCheck = (NSString *)[array objectAtIndex:i];

if ([getDate isEqualToString:stringToCheck]) {
    [signWow setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Your sign is Scorpion"]];
}}
```

It uses **Date Picker** to determine date of birth and then to compare the date with a date from NSArray. But it's too difficult to type in all the dates related to specific **Zodiac sign**.
So, is it possible to make an array which contains all dates between for example 02/12 (**dd/MM**) and 03/15?

**Take a look at screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cdOd.png).**

Please, give some code, because I'm new to Objective-C... :)

Comment: Is this pre- or post-Ophiuchus? ;)

Comment: I'm not so cool at Zodiac, but I have to perform the customer's order :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duncan is right, I was writing you a sample code when he answered the question.....

```
//get date from your picker
NSDate *myDate = [datePickerControl date];

 NSCalendar *gregorianCal = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
 NSDateComponents *dateComps = [gregorianCal components: (NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit)
                                                  fromDate: myDate];
    // Then use it
    int month=[dateComps month];
    int days=[dateComps day];

//I guess there is only two zodiac signs possilble for each month right?
switch (month)
{
    case 1:
    //compare the dates
    if (days<=20)
    {
        //user is Capricorn
    }
    else
    {
        //user is Picses
    }
    break;

    case 2:
    break;

    //you will  have 12 cases and each case will have an if else with corect dates.....

    default;
    break;
}
```

Comment: Switching on the month seems like an unnecessarily complicated solution. Also, building the dates into code limits flexibility -- it might be okay for determining the tropical zodiac (which has fixed dates), but that approach prohibits adding sidereal zodiac (in which the dates aren't fixed) in the future. It'd be much better to store the dates in some sort of table -- maybe a property list or JSON file containing an array of dictionaries, each one containing the corresponding sign and date range.

Answer (score 5):

How about using tuple... (Swift)

```
func getZodiacSign(_ date:Date) -> String{

    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let d = calendar.component(.day, from: date)
    let m = calendar.component(.month, from: date)

    switch (d,m) {
    case (21...31,1),(1...19,2):
        return "aquarius"
    case (20...29,2),(1...20,3):
        return "pisces"
    case (21...31,3),(1...20,4):
        return "aries"
    case (21...30,4),(1...21,5):
        return "taurus"
    case (22...31,5),(1...21,6):
        return "gemini"
    case (22...30,6),(1...22,7):
        return "cancer"
    case (23...31,7),(1...22,8):
        return "leo"
    case (23...31,8),(1...23,9):
        return "virgo"
    case (24...30,9),(1...23,10):
        return "libra"
    case (24...31,10),(1...22,11):
        return "scorpio"
    case (23...30,11),(1...21,12):
        return "sagittarius"
    default:
        return "capricorn"
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should not need to enter every date for each sign. Instead, enter a table of the starting and ending month and day for each sign.

You would then take the user's selected date, use a Gregorian NSCalendar to extract the month and day units from the date, and then compare the user-entered date to the ranges for each sign.

BTW, it's "Scorpio", not "Scorpion".

Answer (score 1):

Here's the most straightforward way to do it. Yes it's long, and yes it's not the most efficient, but it is definitely the easiest to understand, and it's already written for you. Cheers :)

P.S. This is going off of the Tropical zodiac (the standard, as opposed to the Sidereal zodiac based off of the Hindu system), and in response to Zev, Ophiuchus only affected each sign's corresponding constellation, but the sign's and their dates remained unaffected.

Here's the code:

```
-(void)getZodiacFromBirthday {
    NSString *UserBirthday = @"09/09/99";
    NSArray *birthArray = [UserBirthday componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
    NSString *month = birthArray[0];
    NSString *day = birthArray[1];        
        if ([month isEqualToString:@"01"]) {
            if ([day intValue] >= 21) {
                sign = @"Aquarius";
            } else {
                sign = @"Capricorn";
            }
        } else if ([month isEqualToString:@"02"]) {
            if ([day intValue] >= 20) {
                sign = @"Pisces";
            } else {
                sign = @"Aquarius";
            }
        } else if ([month isEqualToString:@"03"]) {
            if ([day intValue] >= 21) {
                sign = @"Aries";
            } else {
                sign = @"Pisces";
            }
        } else if ([month isEqualToString:@"04"]) {
            if ([day intValue] >= 21) {
                sign = @"Taurus";
            } else {
                sign = @"Aries";
            }
        } else if ([month isEqualToString:@"05"]) {
            if ([day intValue] >= 22) {
                sign = @"Gemini";
            } else {
                sign = @"Taurus";
            }
        } else if ([month isEqualToString:@"06"]) {
            if ([day intValue] >= 22) {
                sign = @"Cancer";
            } else {
                sign = @"Gemini";
            }
        } else if ([month isEqualToString:@"07"]) {
            if ([day intValue] >= 23) {
                sign = @"Leo";
            } else {
                sign = @"Cancer";
            }
        } else if ([month isEqualToString:@"08"]) {
            if ([day intValue] >= 23) {
                sign = @"Virgo";
            } else {
                sign = @"Leo";
            }
        } else if ([month isEqualToString:@"09"]) {
            if ([day intValue] >= 24) {
                sign = @"Libra";
            } else {
                sign = @"Virgo";
            }
        } else if ([month isEqualToString:@"10"]) {
            if ([day intValue] >= 24) {
                sign = @"Scorpio";
            } else {
                sign = @"Libra";
            }
        } else if ([month isEqualToString:@"11"]) {
            if ([day intValue] >= 23) {
                sign = @"Sagittarius";
            } else {
                sign = @"Scorpio";
            }
        } else if ([month isEqualToString:@"12"]) {
            if ([day intValue] >= 22) {
                sign = @"Capricorn";
            } else {
                sign = @"Sagittarius";
            }
        }
        NSLog(@"Sign: %@", sign);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

For those using swift, i must thanks Duncan C. his solution helped me a lot:

in case that date is "dd/MM/yyyy"

```
func getZodiacalSign(date:String) -> String {

let f = date.components(separatedBy: "/")
let day = Int(f[0])
let month = Int(f[1])
switch month {
case 1: return (day! >= 21) ? "Aquarius" : "Capricorn";
case 2: return (day! >= 20) ? "Picis" : "Aquarius";
case 3: return (day! >= 21) ? "Aries" : "Pisces";
case 4: return (day! >= 21) ? "Taurus" : "Aries";
case 5: return (day! >= 22) ? "Gemini" : "Taurus"
case 6: return (day! >= 22) ? "Cancer" : "Gemini";
case 7: return (day! >= 23) ? "Leo" : "Cancer";
case 8: return (day! >= 23) ? "Virgo" : "Leo";
case 9: return (day! >= 24) ? "Libra" : "Virgo";
case 10: return (day! >= 24) ? "Scorpio" : "Libra";
case 11: return (day! >= 23) ? "Sagittarius" : "Scorpio";
case 12: return (day! >= 22) ? "Capricorn" : "Sagittarius";
default: return ""
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer for those using Swift. It is based upon Hendra Kusumah's tuple solution, but uses extensions and enums for a neater and more Swift-like answer.

**Usage**

```
let date = Date()
date.zodiacSign // Enum value e.g. .aquarius
date.zodiacSign.rawValue // String value e.g. "aquarius"
```

**Note** - If you wanted the string value to be capitalised or to appear different in another way, either manipulate the string using `date.zodiacSign.rawValue.capitalized` or edit the `ZodiacSign` enum cases e.g. `case aquarius = "Aquarius"`

**Extension**

```
extension Date {

    var zodiacSign: ZodiacSign {
        get {
            let calendar = Calendar.current
            let day = calendar.component(.day, from: self)
            let month = calendar.component(.month, from: self)

            switch (day, month) {
            case (21...31, 1), (1...19, 2):
                return .aquarius
            case (20...29, 2), (1...20, 3):
                return .pisces
            case (21...31, 3), (1...20, 4):
                return .aries
            case (21...30, 4), (1...21, 5):
                return .taurus
            case (22...31, 5), (1...21, 6):
                return .gemini
            case (22...30, 6), (1...22, 7):
                return .cancer
            case (23...31, 7), (1...22, 8):
                return .leo
            case (23...31, 8), (1...23, 9):
                return .virgo
            case (24...30, 9), (1...23, 10):
                return .libra
            case (24...31, 10), (1...22, 11):
                return .scorpio
            case (23...30, 11), (1...21, 12):
                return .sagittarius
            default:
                return .capricorn
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**Enum**

```
enum ZodiacSign: String {
    case aries
    case taurus
    case gemini
    case cancer
    case leo
    case virgo
    case libra
    case scorpio
    case sagittarius
    case capricorn
    case aquarius
    case pisces
}
```